# Is $(p \land q) \to (p \oplus q)$ a tautology?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I am trying to show if this well formed formula is a tautology $(p \land q) \to (p \oplus q)$, I have done the following but I am stuck.

\begin{align}
(p \land q) \to (p \oplus q) &\equiv \lnot(p \land q) \lor (p \oplus q) &\text{By Implication} \\
                  &\equiv (\lnot p \lor \lnot q) \lor (p \oplus q) &\text{By De Morgan}
\end{align}

But I dont know what to do with $p \oplus q$ part.

I know it is an exclusive or, and it is true only when one of them p or q is true, but not both.

What is the next thing to do?

Comment: Just create truth table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Exclusive Or**: $~p\oplus q ~{~\equiv~(p\vee q)\wedge(\neg p\vee\neg q)\\~\equiv~ (p\wedge\neg q)\vee(\neg p\wedge q)}$

Substitute the equivalence of your choice into your expression and continue from there.

Comment: I prefer this one before the power of truth table...

Comment: Does this equivalence have a name? May be "The law of exclusive disjunction", Thank you very much

Comment: The first is the definition of exclusive-disjunction with deMorgan's Law, the second is obtained through distribution and identity and complement laws.

Answer (score 3):

It is not a tautology. If the antecedent $p\land q$ is true, $p$ and $q$ are both true and hence the consequent $p\oplus q$ is false. When in doubt, use a truth table.

Comment: Is not a tautology nor a contradiction, it is a contingency. 

Thank you!

Comment: That's right, since any other values of $p,\,q$ return true due to the antecedent being false.

Answer (score 0):

$$(p \land q ) \rightarrow (p \oplus q) \overset{Def.\oplus}{=}$$

$$(p \land q ) \rightarrow ((p \land \neg q) \lor (\neg p \land  q))\overset{Implication}{=}$$

$$\neg (p \land q ) \lor (p \land \neg q) \lor (\neg p \land  q)\overset{DeMorgan}{=}$$

$$\neg p \lor \neg q  \lor (p \land \neg q) \lor (\neg p \land  q)\overset{Absorption}{=}$$

$$\neg p \lor \neg q$$

... which is clearly not a tautology nor a contradiction, but a contingency.